# what encoding this is?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, mysql, character-encoding

can anyone tell me what encoding is applied on the chinese character, so that chinese characters are converted into this code or text and stored in mysql database :

```
Ã¤Â¸Â­`Ã¥â€ºÂ½Ã¦Â¶Â²Ã¥Å’â€“Ã¥Â¤Â©Ã§â€žÂ¶Ã¦Â°â€Ã¨Â¿ÂÃ¨Â¾â€œÃ¯Â¼Ë†Ã¦Å½Â§Ã¨â€šÂ¡Ã¯Â¼â€°Ã¦Å“â€°Ã©â„¢ÂÃ¥â€¦Â¬Ã¥ÂÂ¸Ã¦Å½Â§Ã¨â€šÂ¡`
```

original chinese characters which are displayed in web page :

```
中国液化天然气运输（控股）有限公司控股
```

on the web page there is a header function is used to make standard chinese chars as follow:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Thanks...

Comment: check the charset of your database-connection, needs to be UTF8 too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: I'm not sure how the ASP.NET tag is related here. Are you using both or something?

Comment: yes i m using mysql database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you decode

```
中国液化天然气运输（控股）有限公司控股
```

as UTF-8, and encode as CP-1252, then you get

```
ä¸­å›½æ¶²åŒ–å¤©ç„¶æ°”è¿è¾“ï¼ˆæŽ§è‚¡ï¼‰æœ‰é™å…¬å¸æŽ§è‚¡
```

When you decode the above as UTF-8 and encode as CP-1252 *once again*, then you get

```
Ã¤Â¸Â­Ã¥â€ºÂ½Ã¦Â¶Â²Ã¥Å’â€“Ã¥Â¤Â©Ã§â€žÂ¶Ã¦Â°â€Ã¨Â¿ï¿½Ã¨Â¾â€œÃ¯Â¼Ë†Ã¦Å½Â§Ã¨â€šÂ¡Ã¯Â¼â€°Ã¦Å“â€°Ã©â„¢ï¿½Ã¥â€¦Â¬Ã¥ï¿½Â¸Ã¦Å½Â§Ã¨â€šÂ¡
```

That's what here is happening.

Answer (score 2):

It is Unicode character set (code points) encoded as UTF-8.